# VBA: Validate List settings

Tags: vba, excel, validation, list

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Worksheets("Drop-down").Select
    For i = 1 To 10
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Select
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            ' Error in this line
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=Range(Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i), Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i).End)
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm getting an error in the line below the comment, yet I don't know how to fix it. It would be great to hear some suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues; the first is you are missing a required argument for the End function, which is a named Excel constant to denote direction.

Instead of 
`Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i).End` on that line try
`Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i).End(xlDown)`

You can use xlLeft, right or up as well, but I'm guessing down is what you are looking for.

Second issue is the value for Formula1 has to be a string address (I think) and you are passing an actual range object.

Try this for that line

`.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Range(Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i), Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i).End(xlDown)).Address`

This worked on my machine, without errors. I of course stubbed in dummy data, so I don't know if it is correct for your worksheet

EDIT (in response to Stan's comment)

There may be a sexier way, but this is a good and simple (which is sexy too, in it's own right); the if statement just checks the cell in the following row. If its non-empty, then it proceeds with the same solution you had before.  If it's empty, then it uses just that one cell as the validation range.

```
For i = 1 To 10
    If Worksheets("Misc").Cells(3, i).Value <> "" Then
        Set validationRange = Range(Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i), Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i).End(xlDown))
    Else
        Set validationRange = Worksheets("Misc").Cells(2, i)
    End If

    With Worksheets("Drop-down").Cells(i, 2).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _ 
                    Formula1:=validationRange.Address.......
```

I combined your

```
Worksheet.Selection
Selection.DoStuff
```

pairs, into

```
Worksheet.DoStuff
```

I think it looks a little nicer.

Let me know if this works for ya!

Comment: That solves the bug. There is one more problem with that line. I'm not sure how to handle cases where the i-th column starting at the second row has only one non-empty entry. It would be great to hear from you again. Thanks.

Comment: @stanigator in that case, you want the validation list to contain just that one cell?

Comment: Ya, I want scenario handling in this case.

Comment: I edited in my code to the original answer for the formatting, let me know if that helps.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'scenario handling', so sorry if I am off track